# Adding to cart functionality with JSP issue

Tags: java, sql, database, jsp

I would like some guidance regarding a class project I am working on. I am unclear about the process in which this works.

I am designing a bookstore application and currently, I am working on the "Add to Cart" feature. What I want to achieve is that when I click on the add to cart button a specific book is added to the cart. I am using this JSP code right now to create the layout of the page in the screenshot below. It fetches the book data from the database.

I want to be able to access the specific ISBN, title, year, and price of the book for which the add to cart button has been clicked and for it to be displayed on my shoppingCart.jsp. Is there a way to do this? I haven't been able to find much guidance and am unclear on the process of sending information. Any help would be appreciated!

```
while (rs.next()) 
            {
            %>  
                <tbody class = "info" style = "width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
                        <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
                        <td><%=rs.getInt(3)%></td>
                        <td>$<%=rs.getInt(4)%></td>
                        <td>
                        <form action="../ShoppingCart/shoppingCart.jsp" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${rs.getString(1)}" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
                            
                        </form>
                        </td>   
                    </tr>    
                </tbody>    
            <% } %>
```

It looks like this as of yet.
[image]

NOTE: Please let me know what other details I can provide to make this clearer.

Comment: Hi, as you are already passing `id` you can write select query on your `shoppingCart.jsp` page to get related data.

Comment: I am passing rs.getString(1) as the value, which is the ISBN. Is that right? also would it just be select id, title, year price from (whatever is the name of the table)?

Comment: Yes that's right .. from table where ISBNcolumn = value which you pass  from form .